# Arduino の自作ライブラリで、使われない関数もリンクされるのでしょうか

Tags: c++, c, arduino, gcc

my_library.h

```
func_A();
func_B();
func_C();
class class_D 
{
    method_a(); 
};
```

my_library.c

```
func_A() {...}
func_B() {...}
func_C() {...}
class_D::method_a(){...}
```

test.ino

```
#include "my_library.h"    
setup() {
    func_B();
}

loop() { }
```

この様な場合、使われない func_A(), func_C(), class_D もリンクされてプログラム領域を消費するのでしょうか？
初心者の稚拙な質問で申し訳ございませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: buildできるんなら、オプション付けてmap出力してみたら分かりますよ。binaryに含まれる関数や定数やらどこにmapされてるか載ってます。

Comment: Arduino IDE 1.8.3 を使っていますが、map出力のオプションを見つけきれませんでした。
google で arduino オプション map出力 で検索しても map関数は出てくるのですが・・・

Comment: 流石にmap fileの出力が無いことないと思うのですが、現物無いので無責任ですみません。。。 http://www.stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=2042 このあたりを見るとmap fileについて語ってるみたいです。

Comment: サイトを参考にやってみます。ありがとうございました。